# Debian Server: setup access via VPN only

Tags: debian, vpn

1) Can I setup easily somehow Debian to be only accessible through a VPN connection? (For example OpenVPN)

2) Do you know a provider which support this feature out of the box? (Server only reachable via VPN connection?

**Problem**
I want to run some code on a server which is located in the internet. But I don't want to manage the server. Also we run services on the server which might have security holes.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use AWS. The steps for this would be in this order:

1. Create a VPC (You can also use the default one).
2. Create an EC2 instance with only private IP and run your service on the machine.
3. Create another EC2 instance and install [Pritunl](https://pritunl.com/) on it. Pritunl is easy to install and can work out of the box. 
   Note: Please add elastic IP to the Pritunl box.
4. Once you have installed Pritunl after referring the docs remove 0.0.0.0 from the routes and add the CIDR for your VPC.
5. In the security group of your server add a rule for port 22 and allow traffic only from the private IP of the Pritunl server.
6. The final step is to download a VPN client (OpenVPN or Pritunl) and create a client profile using the Pritunl server dashboard.

Hope this helps!